# PostgreSQL Hasura Computed field operator does not exist: bigint = text

Tags: postgresql, function, hasura

I'm trying to make a reservation function for a computed field in Hasura (PostgreSQL). The code I'm trying to make gets the **game_length** from the table **rooms** and returns a timestamp with the **game_length + start_time**. However, I am new to functions in SQL and I can't seem to get this function working, as I am getting an error that states: *postgres-error: operator does not exist: bigint = text*. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The test table consists of: id (int), start_time (timestamp), game_length(int), and room_id(int)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.calculate_reservation_total_time(t test)
    RETURNS timestamp with time zone
    LANGUAGE sql
    STABLE
AS $function$  
    SELECT t.start_time + (SELECT count(*) FROM rooms WHERE id=t.room_id ||' minutes')::interval; 
$function$
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `FROM t` or if you use `rooms` then `rooms.room_id`. Not really sure what `t rooms` is there for anyway?

Comment: Please add the definition of your type ```test```. My guess is ```rooms.id``` is of type ```bigint``` while ```t.room_id``` is of type ```text```. So you would need to convert one to the other before comparing them.

Comment: @Islingre got it! it doesent seem that way, there both integer

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your parantheses:

```sql
(SELECT count(*) FROM rooms WHERE id=t.room_id ||' minutes')::interval
```

This will concatenate `t.room_id` with `' minutes'` (thus you get something of type `text`) and then compares this with `id` of `rooms`.

Try following statement:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.calculate_reservation_total_time(t test)
    RETURNS timestamp with time zone
    LANGUAGE sql
    STABLE
AS $function$  
    SELECT t.start_time +
        ((SELECT count(*) FROM rooms WHERE id=t.room_id) ||' minutes')::interval; 
$function$
```